# Xcode 7 simulator screen size is different for iphone 6?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode7

[image][image]I have installed xcode 7,but when i run my app for iphone6,top and bottom of the screen is everything hided.

->my view controller size is 4.7inch.

And it is asking some other simulator downloads.....

Comment: What does the screenshot in your question have to do with the question?

Comment: Please try to go to menu Window->Scale 50%

Comment: @MichaelWang as the iphone ratio i get but the top and bottom have some space...

Comment: @rmaddy why its asking me for some downloads in xcode

Comment: @MichaelWang see the image i was added...

Comment: please insert splash screen for iPhone 6, it will fix this issue..

Comment: @rmaddy thanks .....

Comment: @MichaelWang thanks .....